# Pick highest number in a JavaScript Array I got from a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am making a simple score board for a game I often play with friends using Google Sheets. I am summing up all the points at the top under each player's name and I want to write a custom function to compare these numbers against each other.

After a little bit of googling I stumbled upon a very simple method of picking the highest number out of an array but when I try to use it I only get #NUM! as my output. When I mouse over it it says 'The outcome was not a number".

My code:

```
function Compare_Scores(input) {  
  return Math.max.apply(Math,input );
}
```

And a screenshot off my Sheet:

[image]

If you can help me out I would appreciate it a lot.

Cheers

Comment: So what does the array look like, it sounds like it doesn't contain numbers ?

Comment: @guest271314 `input` should be my array. So B2:I2

Comment: What does `console.log(input)` output ? What is  B2:I2 ?

Comment: the function is perfect the problem might be in the argument ( input )

Comment: @adeneo The array should contain the numbers from B2:I2. If I jsut do `return input` I do get the array as my output. Why it thinks that there are no numbers I can not explain, especially because the function should work with strings as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the default max function?

```
=MAX(B2:I2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to display `input` on the console:

```
console.log(input);
```

There must be some non-numeric data in the array (if it truly is an array).

Comment: When I add that I get a error saying that 'console' is not defined. This is my first time using JavaScript so bear with me if I'm being stupid...

Comment: @TobiasMielke Hmm, not sure why console.log wouldn't work in Chrome. Try running this [jsfiddle test](https://jsfiddle.net/terrymorse/wk9hyq9g/1/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems Math.max.apply(Math,input ) wants to work with columns. To convert you input data to a column array that will work with your function use:

```
=Compare_Scores(transpose( split( arrayformula( concatenate(B2:I6 & char(9)) ), char(9) ) ))
```

But =MAX(B2:I2) is the much easier way to do it.